# Panjer’s family of distributions and Probability Generating Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recursion

*This isn't homework etc just revision where I do not have the solutions and I have no idea how to approach this question. Any tips or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.*

Let the probability function, $p_n = P(N = n)$, of the frequency r.v. N, belongs to the Panjer’s family of distributions, i.e.

$p_n = (a + \frac{b} {n} ) p_{n-1}$

Prove that the probability generating function of the frequency r.v., namely $P_N(z) = E(z^N)$, satisfies the equation the following differential equation

$P′_N(z) = azP'_N(z) + (a + b)P_N(z)$

Prove that the p.g.f. of the aggregate claims $S = X_1 + X_2 + · · · + X_N$,
namely $P_S(z) = E(z^S)$, satisfies the following differential equation

$P′_S(z) = aP_X(z)P'_S(z) + (a + b)P_S(z)P'_X(z)$

Hence show

$P_N(z) = (\frac{1-a} {1-az})^{\frac{b} {a+1}}$

I have tried differentiating this using 
$ P_N(z) = \sum\limits_{0}^{\infty} p_n z^{n}$ 
and Panjer's recursion formulae to obtain

$ P_N'(z) = \sum\limits_{0}^{\infty} n p_n z^{n-1} $

$ P_N'(z) = \sum\limits_{0}^{\infty} n (a + \frac{b} {n} ) p_{n-1} z^{n-1} $

Comment: I would start by writing out $P_N(z)=E[z^N] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n z^n$ and differentiating it. Then use the fact that $p_n=(a+b/n)p_{n-1}$.

Comment: I have just tried that and I have got $P_N'(Z) = sum\ nz^{n-1}p_n +  sum\ (a+b/n)z^n p'_{n-1} - b/n^2 p_{n-1}$

Comment: You got what? Please edit your question to add what you have tried so far instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: sorry I have updated this now

Comment: You shouldn't have anything like $p_n'$... The $p_n$'s are probabilities, so they do not depend on $z$.

Comment: ah okay, how does it differentiate?

Comment: Treat the $p_n$'s as constants with respect to $z$.